# AngularFirestore database, HTML table not automatically updating when data was changed

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I can successfully load my data with correct filtering and pagination. The issue is whenever the Firestore Database was updated, the table was not loaded or updated automatically. I need to refresh the page in order for the new data to be shown on the table.

Here's my **Service.ts**

```
export class ExtractorService {

  constructor(private fstore: AngularFirestore) {}

  //Get all the data in the "sample" collection.
  dbFirestore() {
      return this.fstore.collection('sample').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

This is my **component.ts** in where I load the data.

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {


  filter = new FormControl('');

  sampleData: Observable < any[] > ;
  private questions: any[];

  constructor(private extractorService: ExtractorService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.filterFunction();
  }

  filterFunction() {
      this.sampleData = this.loadQuestionsWithFilter().pipe(
          tap(wData => this.questions = wData),
          concatMap(data => {
              return this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
                  startWith(''),
                  map(text => this.search(text))
              )
          })
      )
  }

  search(text: string): any[] {
      return this.questions.filter(data => {
          const term = text.toLowerCase();
          return data.caseID.toLowerCase().includes(term) || (data.word).toLowerCase().includes(term) || (data.product).toLowerCase().includes(term);
      })
  }

  loadQuestionsWithFilter(): Observable < any[] > {
      return this.extractorService.dbFirestore().pipe(
          map(data => data.map(e => {
              return {
                  id: e.payload.doc.id,
                  caseID: e.payload.doc.data()['caseID'],
                  caseOwner: e.payload.doc.data()['caseOwner'],
                  occurrences: e.payload.doc.data()['occurrences'],
                  product: e.payload.doc.data()['product'],
                  timestamp: e.payload.doc.data()['timestamp'].toDate().toDateString(),
                  word: e.payload.doc.data()['word'],
              }
          }))
      );
  }
```

And this is my HTML code on how I load the data

```
<tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of sampleData | async | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
                  <td>
                      <ngb-highlight [result]=" item.caseID " [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <ngb-highlight [result]=" item.caseOwner " [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ item.occurrences }}</td>
                  <td>
                      <ngb-highlight [result]=" item.product " [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ item.timestamp }}</td>
                  <td>
                      <ngb-highlight [result]=" item.word " [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

BTW, I have a firestore collection name "sample" then the document is auto generated ID.

I'm not sure if I use the `snapshotChanges()` in the service correctly or how I load the data.

Could you please help me to load the table whenever a new data was updated in the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In You Extractor service try change this

```
export class ExtractorService {

  constructor(private fstore: AngularFirestore) {}

  //Get all the data in the "sample" collection.
  dbFirestore() {
      return this.fstore.collection('sample').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => action.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as **You extractClass**;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
      }
  }
```

And in You component page

```
this.extractorService.dbFirestore().subscribe(data => {sampleData = data})
```

Answer (score 0):

change **service.ts**

```
dbFirestore() {
  return this.fstore.collection('sample').valueChanges();
}
```

**why it didn't work:**

snapshot return once than concatMap never subscribe again than u get ur data once

u must use other functions like: valueChanges, ...

[see this TOO IMPORTANT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyHIFofBkGo)